# Fast expansion of shortened URLs using python

Tags: python, urllib2, url-shortener, urlopen

I am writing Python code to expand shortened URLs fetched from Twitter. I have fetched all the URLs and stored them in a text file separated by a newline.

Currently I am using:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
return response.url
```

to expand them.

But the `urlopen()` method doesn't seem to be very fast in expanding the URLs.

I have around 5.4 million URLs. Is there any faster way to expand them using Python?

Comment: Are You doing the requests in sequence?

Comment: Yes I am doing the requests in sequence.

Comment: you want to convert a shorten url to normal url ?

Comment: @Ajay yes. And do this in a small amount of time.

Comment: try requests module.it will be better that urllib

Comment: What are the short URLs like? Can you show some examples?

Comment: here are a few examples: https://t.co/0lka93k2zE
http://t.co/HB2vyuC1tn
http://t.co/6uZ9mJYPlr
http://t.co/CwkvAfzjBT
https://t.co/ocwcnrNE06
https://t.co/KhGym8fdWx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that network calls are slow and urllib blocks until it gets a response. So, for example, say it takes 200ms to get a response from the URL shortening service, then you'll only be able to resolve 5 URLs/second using urllib. However, if you use an async library you should be able to send out lots of requests before you get the first answer. Responses are then processed as they arrive back to your code. This should dramatically increase your throughput. There's a few Python libs for this kind of thing (Twisted, gevent, etc.) so you might just want to Google for "Python async rest".

You could also try to do this with lots of threads (I think urllib2 will release the GIL while it waits for a response, but not sure). That wouldn't be as fast as async, but should still speed things up quite a bit.

Both of these solutions introduce quite a bit of complexity, but if you want to go fast...

Comment: I suspect the URL shortening server might not be too happy with such a thrashing from a single IP address and start blocking. Beware!